# Here is my python code to swapcase the characters in a string .it's not working correct , How to fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

only capital alphabets are converted into small but small letters are not getting converted into capital

```
def swap_case(s):
    pi=list(s)
    for i in range(len(pi)):
        if 'a'<=pi[i]<='z'and ord(pi[i])>0:
            pi[i]=chr(ord(pi[i])- 32)
        if 'A'<=pi[i]<='Z':
            pi[i]=chr(ord(pi[i])+ 32)
    return  (pi)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    result = swap_case(s)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Replace second `if` with `elif`. Currently you are converting lowercase to uppercase and then converting them back.

Answer (score 1):

Python provides functions to address this requirement. Not sure about your exact requirement.

however below answer should swap cases.

```
def swap_case(s):
  swaped= s.swapcase()

  return swaped


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    l = swap_case(s)
    print(l)
```

Comment: The goal is to swap case, not to convert string to lowercase or uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you might be looking for a code which would convert ***lowercase to uppercase and vice-versa***.

**For example**:
***Input:***  Sirius Black 
***Output:*** sIRIUS bLACK

*If so then, the code below might be helpful:*

```
def swapcase (word):
    from collections import deque
    dq = deque(word)
    b=''
    while len(dq)>=1:
        a = dq.pop()
        if a.islower() is True:
            b = a.upper()+ b
        else:
            b = a.lower()+ b
    return b
s = input()
result = swapcase(s)
print (result)
```

Here, I'm using deque ( a double ended queue ) from the 'collections' module for accessing each letter and then converting them as needed and concatenating all of them into a single string.